# How can I make an Expandable Panel editable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I'm currently working on an app for my school project. At the moment I cannot make my expanded panel editable, could anybody tell me how I can make something editable or if it's not possible tell me an alternativ solution? Here's the code btw.:

```
class MyItem {
  MyItem({this.isExpanded = false, required this.header, required this.body});
  bool isExpanded;
  final String header;
  final String body;
}

class fourthPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  list createState() => list();
}

class list extends State<fourthPage> {
  final List<MyItem> _items = <MyItem>[
    MyItem(
        header: "header1",
        body: "text1"),
    MyItem(
        header: "header2",
        body: "text2"),
    MyItem(
        header: "header3",
        body: "text3"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildPage();
  }

  Widget _buildPage() {
    return SafeArea(
        top: true,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("page4"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text(
                  'Assignments:',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                ),
                ExpansionPanelList(
                  expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
                    setState(() {
                      _items[index].isExpanded = !_items[index].isExpanded;
                    });
                  },
                  children: _items.map((MyItem item) {
                    return ExpansionPanel(
                        headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                          return Text(item.header);
                        },
                        isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
                        body: Container(child: Text(item.body)));
                  }).toList(),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Page 1'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(this.context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const FirstPage()));
                  },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Page 2'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(this.context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const SecondPage()));
                  },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Page 3'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(this.context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const ThirdPage()));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I have thought about using onclick in combination with a function but I just can't do it If anybody could help me I would really appreciate it

Comment: Which one you like to make editable?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh The whole thing. The basic idea is, that it can be used as sort of a checklist but expandable.
In the header you enter your class i.e. math and when you expand it, there are the assignments. One should be able to edit both when he wants to

Comment: what about replacing `Text` with `TextFiled` by conditional state `readonly`